# Does " the solution is just to arrive" have a meaning?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice

Does " the solution is just to arrive" can be used in a sentence to emphasise that this is what somebody was looking for?
If I want to advertise something. The solution ( to all your troubles) is just to arrive - new shampoo ( or whatever)
Does it sound good/natural?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your context, but probably it's *not* one where it would be meaningful to say ***The solution is just to arrive***. The only context where those words could make any kind of sense would be if they were intended to mean ***The mere fact of [you, anyone] arriving represents a "solution"***. But realistically, it's just nonsense.

Comment: If I want to advertise something. The solution ( to all your troubles) is just to arrive - new shampoo ( or whatever)

Comment: @justme I believe what you are looking for is "The solution (to all your troubles) is about to arrive" or ""The solution (to all your troubles) has arrived". If you are presenting something that exists, "has arrived" is probably best, if you are presenting something that will available in the near future "is about to arrive" is best.